# Making a Page with a Drag-and-Drop for Imgur Uploads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML page with an `<img>` element. Is it possible to turn that image into a drag-and-drop area, in which the dropped files will be uploaded to my own Imgur account?

This is intended for the latest version of Chrome desktop only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Please make sure your question is [not off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Place the img tag inside the button tag

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">
   <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2016/04/18/01-sea-level-alarm.jpg" />
</button>
```